# How would you explain to someone that connecting to a host via FTP won't compromise the files on their computer?

Tags: security, ftp

In teaching a web development class, I had students SFTP into a sandbox server I created for them so they could work with PHP. One of the students (adult, not traditional student age - bit of a luddite), was hesitant to use it because in their head "now we're going to connect to a remote server" equated to the possibility of someone having access to the files and information on their computer.

How would you respond to this question? It's not something I've ever thought about, but yet I didn't know enough about the FTP protocol itself to come up with a strong explanation of why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would point out that while there are risks from connecting to FTP servers, they do not include the ability for the FTP server to have access to your machine.

- The real risks are that an attacker could sniff usernames and passwords and take, amend or delete the files on the server

This could, of course lead to a valid attack vector as follows:

- Attacker gains access to FTP server
- Attacker compromises a file on the server, replacing it with one including malware
- You download the file, expecting it to be valid
- You run the file, and your machine is compromised

And that compromise could be anything from a bot-net client, a keylogging trojan etc.

You can of course minimise the risks by:

- Using SFTP - which provides for encryption, and stronger authentication
- Provide hashes of the files you want downloaded, so they can be validated
- Virus scan all downloaded files
- Only allow execution of downloaded files in a sandbox

Comment: +1, I like this answer.  You can explain to the student that there are minimal risks to him, and then redirect his concerns/attention to legitimate issues with ftp.  Good summary here Rory.

Comment: The attack vector scenario you outlined is what stumbled me when I was asked this question. You want to tell them to not worry too hard about about it, FTP is no more riskier than other activities we do online (as dslh said)...yet the technical answer is, well, yes there are risks. But it's not as if it's a simple two-way pipe where once the connection is open the server will start grabbing anything it wants. In short: good articulation, accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order for anyone to retrieve files from a clients computer, the client must have opened the SFTP port in his/her firewall as well as allow access to his/her fiels via sftp. These settings default to "denying access" so his/her files cannot possible be compromised. When he SFTP's into a server, the server has allowed him to access files on it. So although he/she is connecting to the server and retrieving files, there really is no way for the server to access any files from his/her computer because the computer will deny access. Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for not assuming the student was a him. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you visit a website, you are "connecting to a remote server". Every time you check your email, you are "connecting to a remote server". Skype? "Connecting to a remote server." In fact, if "connecting to a remote server" worries you then there is literally no point in having an internet connection. FTP seems to scare some people because of the transferring files part, but in truth it's not fundamentally different to any other protocol and certainly not more of a security risk. Back in the day "connecting to a remote server" was an expensive operation that was to be handled with caution but the technology world moves quickly and now it is a normal and mundane exercise.

That is what I would say to him.

Comment: I like the general idea of your answer which is that FTP is no more riskier then other common activities we do online.

Answer (score 0):

Make him think of FTP as something else he may already know, for example, an USB stick.... you are compromising only the files you are putting there; in particular if you are giving it to somebody you don't trust.

Comment: USB sticks in combination with the dreaded Windows Autostart feature have been a spread vector for viruses for a long time, this analogy is likely have a negative effect.